# Is there a method to detect errors before it executes in mql4 codes

Tags: mql4

MQL4 codes are written in C language and basically, there is no method to use error detecting mechanism in C language before executing the code. Is there a special functionality in the Mql4 platform which helps to catch runtime errors before it executes?

Answer (score 0):

No. you cannot throw an error, and you cannot catch it. So be very careful, check that `b!=0` before dividing `a` by `b`, check that `idx>=0` and `idx<array.size` before accessing `array[idx]` and check `CheckPointer(object)==POINTER_DYNAMIC` before calling something with `object`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a mecanisn in mql of detect the errors before executing the code.

So besides the basic checkings of the range limits in the arrays, divisions by 0, passing the parameters witht the right range (price, sl, tp...) to the operations etc. the best way of finding  most of the errors is running a backtest of the strategy you have built for several months using M1. The strategy tester is available on Metatrader.

During the backtesting Metatrader is going to feed your code with a lot of data simulating the actual market, so the code is going to pass through a lot of situations/routines/functions that is going to find later in the actual trading.

The back testing is the best simulation you can do, testing not only the strategy, testing the code itself.

This is not going to guarantee a 100% error free code, but in my case it finds >99% of them.